# Error pip install

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Al intentar instalar pygame con `pip install pygame` me sucede lo siguente:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4hv37aqf\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4hv37aqf\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-i7oc2whu'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4hv37aqf\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4hv37aqf\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4hv37aqf\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4hv37aqf\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4hv37aqf\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: ¿Qué comando ejecutaste?

Comment: pip install pygame

Answer (score 2):

¿ ejecutaste `pip install pygame` ? te recomiendo probar instalando python 3.7.4 en un enviroment y luego:

```
pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Saludos !

Comment: gracias bro, al parecer si era la version de python q no es compatible con el pygame, estaba usando una 3.9

Comment: De nada ! Si te fue útil te agradecería califiques mi respuesta. Suerte !

Comment: Disculpa hermano pero aun no tengo desbloqueada esa opcion, soy new aqui y solo tengo 11 ptos en cuanto pueda te doy el voto, sl2

Answer (score -1):

Si manejas Python desde Anaconda es mucho más fácil, sólo tienes que poner este comando:

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```